# How can I open a new browser TAB?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to write a function that will receive a "browser instance" (and by that I mean `webdriver.Firefox()`) and will open a new tab with a certain URL.

**This is the function:**

```
def open_New_TAB(BrowserInstance, URL):
    if URL_Validation(URL):
        script = "window.open('" + URL + "')"
        BrowserInstance.execute_script(script)
    else:
        print('Invalid URL')
        return
```

`URL_Validation` returns True if the URL is valid

`BrowserInstance` is a return out of the following function, which only returns a "browser instance" of a certain browser type after the `get(URL)` was done:

```
def Open_Browser (URL=None, browserType='FF', Browser_Wait=20, Hide=False, 

    Maximize=False, Retries=3):

    if browserType == 'FF' or browserType == 'FireFox' or browserType == 'Firefox' or browserType == 'firefox':
        # FireFox Parameters
        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.accept_untrusted_certs = False
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = profile, executable_path='G:\\Python\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe')

    elif browserType == 'Chrome' or browserType == 'chrome':
        # Chrome Parameters
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="G:\\Python\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")

    elif browserType == 'IE' or browserType == 'Ie' or browserType == 'Explorer':
        browser = webdriver.Ie(executable_path="G:\\Python\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.8.0\\IEDriverServer.exe")

    else:
        print('No such browser type')

    browser.implicitly_wait(Browser_Wait) # Implicit wait
    browser.set_page_load_timeout(20) # Set the Timeout for waiting till the page loads

    for attempt in range(Retries):
        try:
            browser.get(URL)
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Timeout Expired at the:", attempt+1,'attempt')
    #         browser.close()
            continue   
    return browser
```

I was expecting that the `open_New_TAB` will open a new TAB in the same browser window that was opened by the `Open_Browser` function after running the following script:

```
browser = Open_Browser('http://10.0.1.76')
open_New_TAB(browser, 'http://10.0.7.131')
```

But, unfortunately the result was that a new browser window was opened for `'http://10.0.7.131'`.

i don't understand why i got a new window instead of a new TAB because when I use the following script i do get the new TAB. And this script is exactly the same but without the function

```
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
 driver.get("https://10.0.1.76")
 driver.execute_script("window.open('https://10.0.1.76')")
```

I would appreciate it very much if someone will tell me what I am doing wrong. It is OK if you have another way to accomplish the task of opening a new TAB. By the way I have tried to use: `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')` but without success (I didn't get a new TAB nor an exception)

Comment: I am guessing that the reason for not being able to open a new TAB to the 'browser' instance is because I am not using the default profile. But, still I don't have a clue on how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

**You are getting a new window because you are asking for a new window**

The JavaScript you are using says it right in the command. There is a setting in Firefox to open new windows in tabs, but I'm not sure if it will work in Selenium testing.

It's called `browser.link.open_newwindow`. A value of 2 is off and a value of 3 in on. You can try setting the value via a profile and see what happens.

Comment: This JavaScript actually does open a new TAB but only when I don't set a profile. I've been looking for the setting that you suggested but haven't found it under the FireFoxProfile class. Where can I find it ?

Comment: Neither webdriver.FirefoxOptions nor webdriver.FirefoxProfile include any attribute that might relate to this issue. How can I set this attribute ? And how does my profile effect the ability to open a new TAB ?

Answer (score 1):

As MivaScott said

> It's called browser.link.open_newwindow. A value of 2 is off and a value of 3 in on. You can try setting the value via a profile and see what happens.

This is correct but as far as I know it is impossible to change this value since it is a frozen value. I tried this before and that's what I concluded. I switched to chrome to work around this issue, but ofcourse if you are bound to use firefox I am afraid you will need to do something like downloading the firefox driver source code, manually set this hard coded value to the correct value (2, I assume) and build the webdriver from that edited source.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you and Miva are saying, i have been dealing with this issue for too long. How can you tell that this is a frozen value ? And also, how could it be that if I were not using the profile then the addition of a new TAB was possible ?

Comment: When I was experiencing this issue I used Visual Studio debugger to dig a little deeper in understanding the root cause of the error when I was trying to set this value myself. It then showed me that this value is frozen and thus cannot be changed. Using the default profile was no option for me but would you mind checking what profile it is using when u do so? I'm guessing it's the same profile you would use when normally using Firefox, but it could also be that a new temporary profile is being used.

Comment: I would gladly check which profile am I using when I am not editing the profile. But, I don't know how to do that, I am not that experienced. Where and how should I check this ?

Comment: When you started the driver you should go to 'about:support' in firefox, there should be a link (button) to open your current profile folder.

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't find it

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Your last comment did help. Through the Troubleshooting Information screen I revealed that In both cases the Profile folder field is clear. But, the other thing that I found out is that for some reason the default webdriver (without any profile) doesn't show the 'browser.link.open_newwindow' value in the Important Modified Preferences while in the case that I have set a profile the 'browser.link.open_newwindow' value is 2

Comment: The question is: is there a way to set a profile without setting the 'browser.link.open_newwindow' ?

Comment: Maybe you could try to manually make a new profile using Firefox, make a copy of this profile and place it somewhere in your project's directory. In your code you should be able to make your driver use that profile. That might solve it, since a regular profile made manually allows for tabs to open (obviously).

Comment: I would have tried that if I knew how. At this point I will leave my curiosity aside and use two browser windows. It looks like too much effort just for the purpose of opening a new TAB while working with two is good enough for me